# How implicit picks up up the second argument of method?

Tags: scala

I'm new in scala, so getting difficulty to visualize what's happening in below code.

I've one `Dataset` and it has one map function.

here is map function

```
def map[U](func: MapFunction[T, U], encoder: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
```

as we can see its taking two parameters, `func trait (interface in java) and Encoder trait`

In my code, there is one function as below where am using my Dataset, like this

```
    def myDef(spark : SparkSession, dataset: DataSet) : Dataset[MyType] {
    
         import spark.implicits._
         dataset.map{ x=>  //here is one Row set from Dataset
    
         //then extracting values from Row
    
         //then assign those extracted values to my object
             
         MyType(val1, val2 etc)
                          
    }            
  }            
}
```

My understanding is, when its directly `map{ x=> }`, its a implementation of `MapFunction` trait on any anonymous class (`thinking from java point of view`), but how the second parameter (`encoder`) of `map` function is automatically supplied by just passing  import `spark.implicits._`, its very confusing to me to visualize and understand

My understanding wherever we use `spark.implicits._`, it will provide the extra functionalities defined with addition to already provided in class.

But still not able to clearly understand that, how come by just adding `spark.implicits._` tells `map` to pick `MyType` as second parameter and use it ? How its being even used ?

Because in Java, even after implementation of interface parameter of `map` method, had to pass `Encoder type`, here in scala its too confusing to understand/visualize.

Can anyone please help me on this understand ? it will help to me have clear understanding what's happening here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` method that is being picked up here is not the one you think, it's:

```scala
def map[U](func: (T) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
```

*See [Scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#map%5BU%5D(func:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$6:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D).*

It is very similar but an important thing is that there is 2 "groups" of parameters: the first one having only one parameter `func` and the second having one parameter `arg0: Encoder[U]` but with a special indicator: **`implicit`**.

`implicit` on a parameter instructs the compiler to automatically pass a value of the desired type marked as `implicit` as well without you having to explicitly pass it.

In your case `import spark.implicits._` imports some values (marked as `implicit`) in the scope, including a `implicit val whatever: Encoder[U]`. And then the compiler is able to find this value and pass it to the method.

*Note: it's actually slightly more complex because here the expected implicit parameter is generic. The `import` will actually import a `implicit def whatever[U]: Encoder [U]` but the idea is the same.*

EDIT: and the `U` that the compiler must know to find the correct `Encoder[U]` is resolved thanks to the 1st parameter as well as the return type you declared: `MyType`.